# Notify Multiple Addresses of Answers

Tags: feature-request, notifications, email

I've just posted a question on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/15038/graphic-design-in-outlook-html-email) on behalf of a colleague. I've put my email address in at the bottom to be notified of answers, but it would be even better if I could put multiple addresses in (maybe comma- or semicolon- delimited) so we could both be notified.

Comment: See also [Notify more frequently than once a day?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14555/notify-more-frequently-than-once-a-day/14600#14600) in which Jeff states: *"Part of the implicit contract at SO is that you "pay it forward" and help others answer their questions while you're getting an answer to your own question."* So: visit the communities!

Comment: I guess this is `[status-declined]` as per [multiple e-mail notifications - request - regd.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73637/multiple-e-mail-notifications-request-regd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you won't get immediate notification. Those emails are sent out on a daily basis. In theory you could just forward along the responses when they come to your email at that time.

Only reason I am hesitant to advocate for multiple email addresses if for the potential of abuse. You could in theory set it to send notifications to multiple people, but those others may not have a way to stop the emails from coming, whereas you could just uncheck the mark to stop the delivery.

Comment: Forwarding the email is what I'm going to do but I thought it was worth asking the question.

I had the abuse thought too but I'd like to think the SO users are a bit better than that :-)

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a very specialized situation that doens't call for a general solution.  I'd recommend you do one of the following:

- have the colleague post the question, or
- forward the emails to him/her.