# slow email notification

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, notifications, email

I've noticed I get very slow email notifications from SO. The checkbox says it will notify me daily, but generally two (2) days lapse before I receive a notice of any responses.

I've tested this by inserting dates in some of my posts.

Two days. That seems to be the best response time I can get.

Comment: Do you visit the site between then?

Answer (score 2):

I would agree with that.

Today (25th) I was informed by email of some responses to my questions on the 22nd.

I haven't looked into what effect timezone differences may have made, but the 2 day delay seems about right.

(and I visit the site every day).

Comment: I'm surprised you got an email notification. If you visit the site every day, you do not need one, do you?

Comment: Not really. I shouldn't bother to request it, should I? ;-D

Answer (score 1):

see

[Notify more frequently than once a day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14555/notify-more-frequently-than-once-a-day/14600#14600)