# Why do I get an email the next day?

Tags: feature-request, notifications

I already accepted an answer and upvoted it, yet I continue to get annoying emails a day or two later that say "1 Question Has 1 Answer"... no shit I already accepted it two days ago! Please make emails more aware.

Comment: By "email" do you mean a real e-mail to `yourName@domain.com` or just the little envelope icon on the site lighting up? The icon thing has been reported dozens of times, and it doesn't seem like they're going to do anything about it.

Comment: @Popular, this sounds like real emails.  Personally, I can understand up to a 24 hour delay if a script runs daily, but I've gotten emails well past 24 hours.  I like the request that emails only get sent if an answer hasn't been accepted.

Comment: @rchern, I've never used the "Notify  daily of any new answers" feature, so I don't know what wording those e-mails have. The text the OP provided does look a lot like what's shown on the top bar/banner notification thing, though, so I wanted to clarify.

Comment: @Popular, the wording is the same on the email.  Email generally isn't a term that confuses people.  I guess only one way to find out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [slow email notification](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23442/slow-email-notification) -- we feel your pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be slightly better now.

I still wonder why sometimes I get notification emails and sometimes I don't, though.