# Receiving emails

Tags: support, notifications, email

I would like to receive emails carrying question and answers posted on SO. Do you know how to do that? I clicked on the NOTIFY checkbox with my GMAIL, but until know I received only 1 mail (with related responses) 2 days ago to a question I asked on January.

Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: The RSS feeds might be what you are after.

Comment: dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24659/instant-email-alerts-and-notifications

Answer (score 1):

There is an rss feed for each question, and there are free services to turn rss feeds into e-mails.  I suggest one of those.

Answer (score 0):

Email notifications will be quite slow, and that is by design.

see:

[Notify more frequently than once a day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14555/notify-more-frequently-than-once-a-day/14600#14600)