# I am not notified

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, notifications

I asked a question in Stackoverflow.com and the question was moved to meta.stackoverflow.com after a while. But I was never notified for any of the answers posted on the same issue. I am not sure why was that. Was that because my question was moved to Meta.Stackoverflow.com and I was not a member of Meta at that time? Or there was some another reason working behind the scenes?

Comment: you haven't associated your SO and Meta accounts yet.  the notifications will probably show up (on meta) once you do.

Comment: is this your question?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40478/are-there-any-categories ... once your accounts are associated your meta user will own that question again.

Comment: oh yes, thats my question and my accounts are associated now.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to not being notified about the Meta replies (hard to tell from your phrasing BTW), then its because you didn't have an account on Meta.

As a side note, you really should associate your accounts. It will help if a question is ever moved in the future.

Comment: Anon,
          I think I had just connected both accounts before asking this question. The reason why I am so sure is that I can see My StackOveflow acount in Accounts Tabs--> related accounts section.

Comment: @californicated: nope, you still haven't associated them.  the reason why i'm so sure is that they aren't listed when *i* look at your meta account -> Accounts Tabs.  you're probably seeing the site say *"hey! looks like these accounts are related! want to associate them now?"* ... you need to click to actually get them associated.

Comment: Anon, I am sorry for the late reply. Yes, what you were saying was right. I have associated them now. But there is one more option which seems to be there. This option says "Copy Profile". Should I go ahead and do that?

Comment: @californicated: that's up to you. If you want your profiles to be the same across sites its an easy way to move the information without having to re-type it.

Answer (score 1):

See [Receiving emails](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40537/receiving-emails/40538#40538)

Apparently SO does not do email notifications...

Comment: Hey Grant,
             The link you forwarded tells me that the feature is broken in StackOverflow and  the answer above tells me that this is because I have not attached my meta to the SO. I am not sure what could be the precise reason. By the way I think i have now attached my Meta to SO. IS there any way to know whether they both are connected or not?

Please don't mind my silly question. This is my just second day on the site.

Comment: For associations, go to your profile page, and open the Accounts tab. That will show your associations, if any, with the other sites.

Comment: Regarding your comment, the situation may be due to you not being registered on Meta yet, so you don't have ownership of the question, hence you wouldn't receive the notifications. At which point, the link I posted may or may not still be relevant to this situation.

Comment: So you mean to say that the association between two accounts does not guarantee the notification?

Comment: I  think that I am  making matter complex here. Well, I am able to get notifications when I log on to SO account but I am talking about eMial notification that I get on my yahoo account or something.

Comment: I see you've added the association now. That's one step done. Back to the link I posted, it seems SO does not do email notifications, I don't know if this includes the other sites as well.

Comment: So none of the users on the site are notified, and have to check whether the discussions are driven further or not, manually?

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if the user was notified on the original site that a question had been migrated; otherwise the only way to see what happened to the question is to explicitly go to it and follow the migration link.