# Immediate inbox notifications I can get on my mobile

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, global-inbox, email

There's been some old discussions [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24659/instant-email-alerts-and-notifications) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6557/instant-e-mail-notifications-of-answers-to-questions/31587#31587) about receiving immediate emails when your inbox has new messages, and some reasons were given why not to do this (spamming, people will stop using the site, etc).

Is there anyway I can receive immediate notifications to my mobile when there is activity in my questions/answers? Thing is, sometimes I ask a question, and someone answers 2 hours later, and I only see it 3 hours after when I get my email notification (the minimal email period is 3 hours).

Then I comment, and he receives it 3 hours later, and then it's night and a discussion can go on for days.

What I'd like, is to get a notification on activity that will actually get my attention. Email is nice because my mobile can make a sound when I get an email. But anything will do.

Comment: There's probably something on http://stackapps.com/ that would do that, if not feel free to make one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<s>We are currently working on mobile apps that will provide this functionality, along with many other features. You can probably expect to see them for yourself in 6-8 weeks (but don't hold me to that).</s>

In the meantime, for a workaround there are always RSS feeds - each question has a [question feed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/180638) link at the bottom of the page. It won't pick up comments, but it will pick up answer activity.

As of January 27<sup>th</sup> 2014 we have official [Stack Exchange for Android app](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-for-android-is-here/), and as of May 8<sup>th</sup> 2014 we have official [Stack Exchange for iPhone app](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/stack-exchange-for-iphone-is-here/), both featuring immediate inbox notifications.

Comment: 1+ for 6-8 weeks ;)

Comment: Thanks, good to know. I was looking for an original app but all I could find was third parties with few downloads so I don't usually install those.

Comment: This is now `status-implemented`; iOS and Android apps are here!

Comment: Took the liberty to edit to reflect the apps, feel free to edit or rollback if something is wrong.

Comment: Looks fine to me, thanks!