# notify email doesn't work

Tags: support, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notify more frequently than once a day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14555/notify-more-frequently-than-once-a-day)

When I click the notify  daily of any new answers check box, notifications aren't sent.  My work email server may be filtering them, but can someone provide and example of a notification email so I can let the mail admin guys know what to look for?

Comment: Yes it does, it just works much, much slower than expected. Emails might take a few days to arrive. This is status-bydesign, from what I know of.

Comment: @alex that is not working as it used to nor as the text next to the check box states it will work.  It should be each day if there have been any updates an email should be sent if not then one should NOT be sent.  This used to work great in the past but it hasn't worked well much of this year.

Answer (score 2):

Notification emails don't arrive on every new answer, but rather abridged, once per day (or two I guess), if there is a new answer on that day.

Comment: But that is not working, I get many responses and it could take a week before I see a notification e-mail.  This used to give be a daily notification of all updates but now its like I don't get most of them, and then days or weeks later one actually gets sent for just the updates for that day, all the previous ones are never to be seen.

I checked the JUNK e-mail and they are not there, and since I do get the occasional one it seems like something is wrong on the stack side.

Comment: Might I also add that I'm reading your comment today, after some 40 days!