# Not getting email alerts on answers on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, email, preferences

Not getting email alerts on answers on my questions on stackoverflow.com

- Used to get it earlier (>1 month back), but not getting alerts in recent times
- Email field in profile is filled
- In prefs, "I'd like email notifications of activity on questions I've asked" is ticked.

What is missing?

Is it possible that signing up on another Stack Exchange community (say, Server Fault), on which by default, "I'd like email notifications of activity on questions I've asked" is unchecked affects same preference on stackoverflow.com? If so, it is a bug.

Comment: Unless there is a bug in the notifications, this is a duplicate of [Notify more frequently than once a day?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14555/notify-more-frequently-than-once-a-day)

Answer (score 1):

The emails only go out once a day.  The last time one of your questions was answered was only 20 hours ago.  I think the "once a day" thing makes sense.  In the first few hours after I ask a question I'm going to be actively working on the problem and checking the site manually for notifications.  I don't need the emails as well in this time frame.  After that, new answers aren't so critical that I need to be notified **immediately** by email, so once a day is often enough.

If you need updates for a particular question more quickly than once a day, you can also subscribe to its RSS feed.

Comment: Actually I did not even get a mail for an answer received >10 days back ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059023). I think settings were the same even then.

Comment: And of course, the mail for the last SO question did not arrive till now (long after 24 hours). So, looks like it is a bug.

Comment: I haven't received notifications of answers to my questions since the beginning of 2014.   I've posted several questions, most of them have been answered, but no notifications.     Preferences are set correctly, i..e,  I've checked the box to receive notifications to questions that I've asked.    Seems like I'm not the only one in this situation???

Comment: @LeoSimon You're only emailed if you have unread messages in your inbox.

Comment: In the past I used to get emails whenever somebody responded to a question that I posted.    Would a response to a question of mine result in a message in my inbox?    If so, then I haven't been receiving them.     If not, then how can i ensure that when somebody responds to a question of mine, then I somehow receive an email notification?     Thanks for your help, Bill