# Why not notify instantly when have a new answer?

Tags: feature-request, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notify more frequently than once a day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14555/notify-more-frequently-than-once-a-day)

In below to place to write this, I have:

```
 Notify (my e-mail) daily of any new answers
```

The problem is: daily is a lot of time, why not instantly? If two or more answer happens for one question, I  only will be notify one time, until I enter in the Stack Overflow, like same forums.

I don't like this system, I have to enter all time to see if my question was quickly answered (this is common). For old post, ok, one day isn't a lot time, but for a new question...

What do you thing?

EDIT

Wow.. It was fast :P Well, I saw it was not a good post.. Anyway, now I know it... :)

Edit 2

Sorry for the noise (I search it before post, but didn't find that question)... In less than 10 minutes, I gain -5 and block my question! This is my personal record!!!

Comment: Active participation is the goal. If you have to experience the *horror* of actively monitoring your own question, *perfect! The system is working!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might be a lot of emails.  It is not worth it to spam users who want to be notified.  If you want updates more often than a day login to SO and check.

Comment: Like I say above, you can CHOSE it. An it is not for ALL question. If some thing is is causing a lot of new e-mail, turn it OFF.