# I don't receive email notification of new replies to my questions or get them after a few days!

Tags: support, global-inbox, email-notification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notify more frequently than once a day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14555/notify-more-frequently-than-once-a-day)

I have selected "Email me my unread inbox messages every 3 hours" in the "email settings" section of the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ (aka global inbox).

For some questions I've never gotten any notification and for others I've gotten one only after a couple of days. Is there anything I'm missing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Scrooge: I don't want to be 'notified more frequently than once a day' -- as I said for some questions I don't get a notification at all and that's the problem.

Comment: Jeff's answer applies in this case too. E-mail is designed to be "slow" to encourage users to visit the sites.

Comment: If that's the case, then why does the site allows me to select "Email me my unread inbox messages every 3 hours" in the "email settings" section?

Comment: Pics or it didnt happen

Comment: What @Gabe says - where is that setting? I can't see it.

Comment: You probably opened the Inbox from within Stack Exchange site (no matter which) thus all the items got "read" status and would not be sent to your email. As it says:  "Email me my **unread** inbox messages every 3 hours"

Comment: @Gabe I've added it now for convenience.

Comment: @Pekka - see above. :)

Comment: @Shadow oh! Never seen that. Thanks.

Comment: @Pekka - me too, this question made me look and I've found it. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: "You probably opened the Inbox from within Stack Exchange site (no matter which) thus all the items got "read" status" Yes! That should be the reasobn. I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: Cheers @Rain, posted this as answer so the question can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably opened the Inbox from within Stack Exchange site (no matter which) thus all the items got "read" status and would not be sent to your email.

As it says:

> Email me my **unread** inbox messages every 3 hours

Comment: I agree this is probably the reason, and that is 100% status-by-design