# is it possible to get emailed when somebody answers or comments

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notify more frequently than once a day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14555/notify-more-frequently-than-once-a-day)

I get email updates but often like a day later. Is there a way to immediately get updated? Can I get this sent as a text to cell phone?

Comment: So do you want emails or text messages?

Comment: uhhh... either is fine