# multiple e-mail notifications - request - regd

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, email-notification

For a question abc, I would like to add multiple email accounts to it 
(notify abc of daily answers) so that some of friends can be alerted of possible updates to abc.

Comment: Why not have your friends visit the site?

Comment: alert wuld be more helpful I think.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notify Multiple Addresses of Answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10695/notify-multiple-addresses-of-answers)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible -- otherwise you could "sign up" a bunch of people for notifications and effectively annoy them with spam.

At the very least the emails would have to be *confirmed* before this could happen, making this impractical.

I suggest you encourage your friends to subscribe to tags, via email or RSS, instead -- https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/subscribe-to-tags-via-emai/